# Android Studio - UnsatisfiedLinkError for prebuilt native library

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I'm trying to implement the SoundTouch C++ library into my android project.

Gradle build works fine. But, when I call some SoundTouch related method from the code, the app crashes and I get the following error:

> `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dancam.chords-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.dancam.chords-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libsoundtouch.so"`

Apparently it does not find the `libsoundtouch.so` within the libs arm64 folder. My file tree looks like this:

[image: filetree]

**Any clue why this happens?**

EDIT:

I copied my `SoundTouch.java` class in `main/java/net/surina/soundtouch`

Still when I run it I get this:

> `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long soundtouch.SoundTouch.newInstance() (tried Java_soundtouch_SoundTouch_newInstance and Java_soundtouch_SoundTouch_newInstance__)`

as if it was only in the `soundtouch` folder.

This is how my project dir looks like:

[image: filetree2]

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but with no luck

Comment: NO, sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs should list the relevant directories

Comment: @AlexCohn What do you mean? should it point to the `jniLibs` folder? Or to the actual `.so` file?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough; all you had to do (compared to the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObDaQ.png), was to rename `app/libs` to `app/jniLibs`, and not touch **build.gradle**. I have no idea what changes you made to our project since then.

Comment: Android Studio 'Build' menu has 'Analyze APK': use it to see the result of your build before you try to install it.

Comment: @AlexCohn after resetting to thge previous backup and renaming the folder without having any line in the build.gralde, I still get the PathClassLoader error

Comment: btw is it normal that on the most top level I have a folder named app and anoter named with the actual project name which is Chords2? You can see it from the image

Comment: <s>Did you look at your APK in the analyzer? Does it have the expected so files?</s> You see that the error is different now; the library was found and loaded, but now the native method has not been found.

Comment: Now you have touched the new class of problems. Java native methods are hardcoded. If you rename a Java class (including the package name), you must recompile the C++ code, too. The solution is to keep the Java classes and packages same as dictated by the native library. You can keep the app package name as you wish; you only keep the Java class that has the native methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;NR: rename the `app/libs` folder to `app/jniLibs`.

---

When you use prebuilt libraries, you must instruct Android Studio where it can find them. The default location is jniLibs under the module root directory.

You can instruct Android Studio to pick the libraries elsewhere: add the following to the **android {}** block in **build.gradle** script for your module (app):

```
sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs', 'src/main/jniLibs', '/absolute/path/to/prebuilt']
```

Each **jniLibs** src directory is expected to have subdirectories with **lib××××.so** files in them: arm64-v8a armeabi armeabi-v7a mips mips64 x86 x86_64. Not all ABI subdirectories must be present, and you have further control which ABIs will be used for your APK, with [**ndk.abiFilters**](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.html) flag.

As you can see, it can pick up more than one set of libraries, and will pack all **lib××××.so** files into your APK. It may fail if there is a conflict (e.g. it finds both `libs/x86/libqq.so` and `absolute/path/to/prebuilt/libqq.so`), but it doesn't care if the files under **x86**, **armeabi**, **mips64** have any relationship between them.

---

When you use a prebuilt C++ library in your Java (e.g. Android) application, you must keep the names of Java classes (including the package names) as commanded by the native code.

For example, the [SoundTouch](https://sourceforge.net/projects/soundtouch/) library should be accessed from `net/surina/soundtouch/SoundTouch.java`.

You can use whatever app package name; you only keep the Java classes that have the native methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean for `module root` directory exactly? Furthermore, the 'absolute path to prebuilt' is it to the jniLibs dir or to the actual .so file, if the last, how do I import all of them for all the different architectures

Comment: I only show different ways to point to the directory which contains subdirectories with predefined names: x86, x86_64, armeabi, *etc*. You should choose whatever suits you best.

Comment: I see, so no matter which one I import. I updated the question with the line I wrote in gradle plus another error happening when trying to run the app. It seems to find the method now but somehow does not find any implementation?

Comment: In your case, module root is `~/Developer/AndroidProjects/Chords2/app/app`

Comment: After moving the `SoundTouch.java` class into net/surina/soundtouch I'm getting an error as if it is only in the `soundtouch` folder instead of the whole `net.surina.soundtouch. Please check my edited question

Comment: I am afraid you need somebody to simply build the project for you. Just google for a freelancer - it may be quite affordable

Comment: Why can't I build it myself?

Comment: I don't know why. I can tell you why I suggest you the alternative. Your first question about this SoundTouch appeared here more than 10 days ago. You have spent much more time on trying to set it up than is reasonable - even if this is only 'elapsed time'. I believe that it should take no more than few hours to prepare a working environment from which you can start doing really interesting things.

Comment: Yes you are right, but this is my hobby not my full time job, so I don't really care about time. I'm willing to learn though, and since this is my first attempt in using the Android NDK, I was expecting to "waste" sometime learning how it works. So please if you can think of a solution, let me know.

Comment: You have chosen a bad starting point to learn the subject. Start with a book, move to online tutorials, study the Google samples.

Comment: Ok I will, still can you help me out with the question? It has still not been answered properly